# Is there a callback for when the title bar is completely hidden?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I've got an activity that's defined like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".DocViewActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    </activity>
```

What I see when starting this activity is, first the UI appears (quick, but animated), then the hiding of the title bar happens, (also quick, but animated).

What I want to do is wait for all of this to finish before proceeding.  I've tried using an `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, but I think (though it's hard to confirm) that it's getting called before the title bar disappears.

So my question is, how can I know when the layout has finished *and* the title bar has disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `OnLayoutChangeListener` on the title bar however I think all hiding animations will be done once you set it in `onCreate` what is the real purpose of this task?

Comment: I need to make some calculations based on the size and location on screen of the view. If I do that too early, I'm off by the height of the title Bar.

Comment: @FredRoss-Perry
To get real size of the screen you can use use `DisplayMetrics`

            `DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
      getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        displayMetrics.heightPixels;` 

and to get position on screen check method:

`View.getLocationOnScreen()`

Comment: My activity contains a custom view, which fills itself in by inflating.  This works fine.  but when I use View.getLocationOnScreen() the view first appears at the top of the screen (y=0), then is pushed down (y=48), then moves up again (y=0), all in the space of bout 650 ms.  What's interesting is that the prior activity *does* show the title bar.  If I set it to NOT show the title bar, I don't get this odd bouncing effect.

Comment: Did you try to force full screen programmatically - 
`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Comment: I tried that without success, but what did finally work for me was:

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);`
`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);`

This prevented the odd "bouncing" effect I was seeing.  And then I use
OnGlobalLayoutListener to wait for the layout.  Thanks.